# Using math in solr if expressions

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am trying to use math in an 'if' statement in solr. What I want to achieve is following, I have a trapeze function defined as:
There are 4 points on the x axis, left_minimum, left_optimum, right_optimum, right_maximum. 
For every value of the field I want to have following outcome:

```
value v 
score s 
maxscore
if (v<left_minimum)
 s = 0;
if (v>right_maximum)
 s = 0;
if (v>=left_optimum AND v<=right_optimum)
 s = maxScore;
if (v>=left_minimum AND v<left_optimum)
 s = maxScore * (v - left_minimum) / (left_optimum - left_minimum)
if (v>right_optimum AND v<=right_maximum )
 s = maxScore * (v - right_optimum) / (right_maximum - right_optimum)
```

The basic idea is to rank results which are "near" the ideal result higher than the results that are too far away.
to achieve this I tried to split my calculation for height in three parts (maxscore is 1.0):

```
heightWM=product(1.0, map(height,160,170,1,0))
&heightWL=if(height < 160 AND height > 150, product(1.0, div(sub(height,160),10)), 0)
&heightWR=if(height < 180 AND height > 170, product(1.0, div(sub(height,170),10)), 0)
&heightW=sum(heightWL, heightWM, heightWR)
```

problem is that solr doesn't like if with mathematical expression. Or at least I haven't find how.
Is there any other possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually found a solution or, better, a workaround.

```
heightWL=if(map(height,160,169,1,0),div(sub(height,160),10),0)
```

so I am basically mapping all values between x and y in a > x and a < y to 1, and all other values to 0. This way if can actually check, since it can work with 1 and 0, and in that case I calculate the subvalue for this area.